# que estilos deberia agregar en mi reporte en xml

Tags: mvc, xml, odoo, style, report

Estoy diseñando un reporte del modelo de odoo en xml pero no entiendo bien la parte de estilos ya que no se bien que estilos agregar para poder ajustar el reporte tengo entendido que se le agregan estilos de bootstrap ya que no estoy haciendo uso de una hoja css

Adjunto codigo:

````
```<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
 <odoo>

<record id="action_report_bascula" model="ir.actions.report">
    <field name="name">Reporte de bascula</field>
    <field name="model">mti_bascula</field>
    <field name="report_type">qweb-pdf</field>
    <field name="report_name">mti_inventory.report_bascula</field>
    <field name="report_file">mti_inventory.report_bascula</field>
    <field name="print_report_name">('Reporte de bascula - %s' %(object))</field>
    <field name="binding_model_id" ref="model_mti_bascula"/>
    <field name="binding_type">report</field>
</record>

<template id="report_bascula">
<t t-call="web.html_container">
    <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <img src="/mti_inventory/static/src/img/logo.png" style="max- 
 height: 90px; margin-left:30px;"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2" style="margin-left:150px; padding-top:50px;">
                    <h5 style="text-align: center;  font- weight:bold; font-size:50px">RECEPCION DE EMBARQUES</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sx-2" style="padding-bottom:10px; margin-top:10px;">
                    <div class="row">
                        <table class="table table-sm" style="border:1px solid #939E9D; border-collapse:collapse;">
                        <tr class=" " style="border:1px solid #939E9D; font-size: 13px;">
                            <td name="vendor_id" class="text-left" style="border: 1px solid #939E9D; padding-left:20px;" ><strong>Proovedor:</strong> <t t-if="o.vendor_id"><span t-field="o.vendor_id"/></t></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class=" " style="border:1px #939E9D; font-size: 13px;">
                                    <td name="driver_truck_id" class="text-left" style="border: 1px solid #939E9D; padding-left:20px;" ><strong style='color:black;'>Operador:</strong> <t t-if="o.driver_truck_id"><span t-field="o.driver_truck_id"/></t></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class=" " style="border:1px solid #939E9D; font-size: 13px;">
                                    <td name="consignment_note" class="text-left" style="border: 1px solid #939E9D; padding-left:20px; background-color:red;"><strong style='color:black;'>Carta Porte:</strong> <t t-if="o.consignment_note"><span t-field="o.consignment_note"/></t></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class=" " style="border:1px solid #939E9D; font-size: 13px;">
                                    <td name="td_number_plate" class="text-left" style="border: 1px solid #939E9D; padding-left:20px;"><strong style='color:black;'>Placas Trac:</strong> <t t-if="o.number_plate"><span t-field="o.number_plate"/></t></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class=" " style="border:1px solid #939E9D; font-size: 13px;">
                                    <td name="consignee_id" class="text-left" style="border: 1px solid #939E9D; padding-left:20px;"><strong style='color:black;'>Consignatario:</strong> <t t-if="o.consignee_id"><span t-field="o.consignee_id"/></t></td>
                        </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
          <div class="clearfix" style="padding-bottom:10px; margin-top:10px;" >
                    <div class="row">
                        <div style="padding-left: 300px" t-attf-class="#{'col-7' if 
       report_type != 'html' else 'col-sm-7 col-md-5'} ">
                          <table class="table table-sm" style="border:1px solid #939E9D; border-collapse:collapse;">
                           <tr class=" " style="border:1px solid #939E9D; font-size: 13px;">
                               <td name="destiny" class="text-right" style="border: 1px solid #939E9D; padding-left:20px;"><strong style='color:black;'>Destino:</strong><t t-if="o.destiny"><span t-field="o.destiny"/></t></td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr class=" " style="border:1px solid #939E9D; font-size: 13px;">
                               <td name="VIA" class="text-right" style="border: 1px solid #939E9D; padding-left:20px;"><strong style='color:black;'>VIA:</strong><t t-if="o.VIA"><span t-field="o.VIA"/></t></td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr class=" " style="border:1px solid #939E9D; font-size: 13px;">
                               <td name="Recive" class="text-right" style="border: 1px solid #939E9D; padding-left:20px;"><strong style='color:black;'>Recive:</strong><t t-if="o.receive"><span t-field="o.receive"/></t></td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr class=" " style="border:1px solid #939E9D; font-size: 13px;">
                               <td name="partner_id" class="text-right" style="border: 1px solid #939E9D; padding-left:20px;"><strong style='color:black;'>Remitente:</strong><t t-if="o.partner_id"><span t-field="o.partner_id"/></t></td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr class=" " style="border:1px solid #939E9D; font-size: 13px;">
                               <td name="seller_id" class="text-right" style="border: 1px solid #939E9D; padding-left:20px;"><strong style='color:black;'>Ejecutivo:</strong><t t-if="o.seller_id"><span t-field="o.seller_id"/></t></td>
                           </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
         </div>
        <table class="table table-sm" style="margin-top:30px;">
                <thead>
                    <th>Ancho</th>
                    <th>Alto</th>
                    <th>Volumen</th>
                    <th>Peso_Bruto</th>
                    <th>Descripcion</th>
                    <th>Palletizado</th>
                    <th>Flejado</th>
                    <th>Sello</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <t t-set="ctd_lineas" t-value="0"/>
                    <tr t-foreach="o.peso_id" t-as="l">
                        <td><span t-field="l.Ancho"/></td>
                        <td><span t-field="l.Alto"/></td>
                        <td><span t-field="l.Volumen"/></td>
                        <td><span t-field="l.Peso_Bruto"/></td>
                        <td><span t-field="l.Descripcion"/></td>
                        <td><span t-field="l.Palletizado"/></td>
                        <td><span t-field="l.Flejado"/></td>
                        <td><span t-field="l.Sello"/></td>
                        <t t-set="ctd_lineas" t-value="ctd_lineas+1"/>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
    </t>
</t>
     </template>


    </odoo>```
````

asi es como tengo estructurado mi reporte en xml y les esto yagregando los estilos de forma directa pero que estilo sdeberia agregarle para ajustar el formato ya que tengo dos tablas una alado de la otra y  quisiera que estuvieran una alado de otra

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

asi  es como aparece el reporte cuando lo descargo que estilos deberia d eagregar para acomodar el encabezado y para poner las tablas una junto a la otra y que haya un minimo espacio de separación

Comment: Para fines de desarrollo rápido puedes ver la versión html del reporte sin necesidad de estarlo descargando: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/es/developer/reference/addons/reports.html#reports-are-web-pages

Comment: nose si me puedas ayudar u orientar con lo que tengo que hacer los reportes la vista del modelo ya lo tengo solo me falta hacer que haga la busqueda por el número y poder obtenerlo en pdf y excel @Legna

Comment: Tienes tres tablas, cuales quieres poner juntas?

Comment: las pruimeras dos bueno lo que te puse en el comentario anterior es de otra preguna que hice

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/571407/como-estructurar-el-modelo-de-busqueda-del-informe-avanzado  es de esta @Legna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar [boostrap y su grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) para lograr lo que quieres:

```html
<template id="report_bascula">
  <t t-call="web.html_container">
    <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
      <div class="header">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-2">
            <img
              src="/mti_inventory/static/src/img/logo.png"
              style="max-height: 90px; margin-left: 30px"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-2" style="margin-left: 150px; padding-top: 50px">
            <h5 style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold; font-size: 50px">
              RECEPCION DE EMBARQUES
            </h5>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

        <!-- -------------------------------------------- -->
        <!-- -------------------------------------------- -->
        <!-- Las clases de bootstrap row y col-x van aquí -->
        <!-- -------------------------------------------- -->
        <!-- -------------------------------------------- -->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-6">
            <table
              class="table table-sm"
              style="border: 1px solid #939e9d; border-collapse: collapse"
            >
              <tr class=" " style="border: 1px solid #939e9d; font-size: 13px">
                <td
                  name="vendor_id"
                  class="text-left"
                  style="border: 1px solid #939e9d; padding-left: 20px"
                >
                  <strong>Proovedor:</strong>
                  <t t-if="o.vendor_id"><span t-field="o.vendor_id" /></t>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr class=" " style="border: 1px #939e9d; font-size: 13px">
                <td
                  name="driver_truck_id"
                  class="text-left"
                  style="border: 1px solid #939e9d; padding-left: 20px"
                >
                  <strong style="color: black">Operador:</strong>
                  <t t-if="o.driver_truck_id"
                    ><span t-field="o.driver_truck_id"
                  /></t>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr class=" " style="border: 1px solid #939e9d; font-size: 13px">
                <td
                  name="consignment_note"
                  class="text-left"
                  style="
                    border: 1px solid #939e9d;
                    padding-left: 20px;
                    background-color: red;
                  "
                >
                  <strong style="color: black">Carta Porte:</strong>
                  <t t-if="o.consignment_note"
                    ><span t-field="o.consignment_note"
                  /></t>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr class=" " style="border: 1px solid #939e9d; font-size: 13px">
                <td
                  name="td_number_plate"
                  class="text-left"
                  style="border: 1px solid #939e9d; padding-left: 20px"
                >
                  <strong style="color: black">Placas Trac:</strong>
                  <t t-if="o.number_plate"><span t-field="o.number_plate" /></t>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr class=" " style="border: 1px solid #939e9d; font-size: 13px">
                <td
                  name="consignee_id"
                  class="text-left"
                  style="border: 1px solid #939e9d; padding-left: 20px"
                >
                  <strong style="color: black">Consignatario:</strong>
                  <t t-if="o.consignee_id"><span t-field="o.consignee_id" /></t>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
          <div class="col-6">
            <table
              class="table table-sm"
              style="border: 1px solid #939e9d; border-collapse: collapse"
            >
              <tr class=" " style="border: 1px solid #939e9d; font-size: 13px">
                <td
                  name="destiny"
                  class="text-right"
                  style="border: 1px solid #939e9d; padding-left: 20px"
                >
                  <strong style="color: black">Destino:</strong
                  ><t t-if="o.destiny"><span t-field="o.destiny" /></t>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr class=" " style="border: 1px solid #939e9d; font-size: 13px">
                <td
                  name="VIA"
                  class="text-right"
                  style="border: 1px solid #939e9d; padding-left: 20px"
                >
                  <strong style="color: black">VIA:</strong
                  ><t t-if="o.VIA"><span t-field="o.VIA" /></t>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr class=" " style="border: 1px solid #939e9d; font-size: 13px">
                <td
                  name="Recive"
                  class="text-right"
                  style="border: 1px solid #939e9d; padding-left: 20px"
                >
                  <strong style="color: black">Recive:</strong
                  ><t t-if="o.receive"><span t-field="o.receive" /></t>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr class=" " style="border: 1px solid #939e9d; font-size: 13px">
                <td
                  name="partner_id"
                  class="text-right"
                  style="border: 1px solid #939e9d; padding-left: 20px"
                >
                  <strong style="color: black">Remitente:</strong
                  ><t t-if="o.partner_id"><span t-field="o.partner_id" /></t>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr class=" " style="border: 1px solid #939e9d; font-size: 13px">
                <td
                  name="seller_id"
                  class="text-right"
                  style="border: 1px solid #939e9d; padding-left: 20px"
                >
                  <strong style="color: black">Ejecutivo:</strong
                  ><t t-if="o.seller_id"><span t-field="o.seller_id" /></t>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12">
            <table class="table table-sm" style="margin-top: 30px">
              <thead>
                <th>Ancho</th>
                <th>Alto</th>
                <th>Volumen</th>
                <th>Peso_Bruto</th>
                <th>Descripcion</th>
                <th>Palletizado</th>
                <th>Flejado</th>
                <th>Sello</th>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <t t-set="ctd_lineas" t-value="0" />
                <tr t-foreach="o.peso_id" t-as="l">
                  <td><span t-field="l.Ancho" /></td>
                  <td><span t-field="l.Alto" /></td>
                  <td><span t-field="l.Volumen" /></td>
                  <td><span t-field="l.Peso_Bruto" /></td>
                  <td><span t-field="l.Descripcion" /></td>
                  <td><span t-field="l.Palletizado" /></td>
                  <td><span t-field="l.Flejado" /></td>
                  <td><span t-field="l.Sello" /></td>
                  <t t-set="ctd_lineas" t-value="ctd_lineas+1" />
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
    </t>
  </t>
</template>
```

Comment: gracias no se si tengas un tiempo para apoyarme con otra pregunta porque si esta un poquito mas compleja @Legna

Comment: @CarlosBaez edite la respuesta. Por favor revisa si te funciona.