# como estructurar el modelo de busqueda del informe avanzado

Tags: python, mvc, odoo, popup, wizard

del modulo que estoy ocupando su finalidad es qu ehaga reportes avanzados basado en los estándares personalizados de odoo pero tengo dudas en cuestión con eso ya que soy primerizo en incorporar odoo con código ya hice el pop up  con el formulario para busqueda pero estuve prbando duiversas estructuras para poder filtrar y obtener el reporte ya que los filtros de la busqueda estas asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y asi lo tengo en el codigo de python:

````
```class Infomecp (models.Model):
_name=('mti_informe_cp')

consignment_note_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='mti.carta.porte', string='Carta Porte')
print_type = fields.Selection(
    [('Sin formato', 'Sin formato'), ('Original', 'Original'), ('Copia', 'Copia')],
    string='Imprimir por')```
````

ya que el primer campo esta ligado a la base de datos de otro modelo ya que va a buscar por número y como podria estrucutrar lo demas ya que el reporte que va a extraer son reportes que pertenecen a otro modelo mas bien la informacion y asi es como lo tengo estrcuturado con esas especificaciones

````
```# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
 import json
 import io
 from xlsxwriter import workbook

from odoo.tools import date_utils
from odoo.exceptions import UserError, ValidationError
from odoo import fields, models, api

try:
from odoo.tools.misc import xlsxwriter
except ImportError:
import xlsxwriter



class Infomecp (models.Model):
_name=('mti_informe_cp')

consignment_note_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='mti.carta.porte', string='Carta Porte')
print_type = fields.Selection(
    [('Sin formato', 'Sin formato'), ('Original', 'Original'), ('Copia', 'Copia')],
    string='Imprimir por')

def get_excel_informe_cp_report(self):
    datas = self._get_data()
    return {
        'type': 'ir.actions.report',
        'report_type': 'xlsx',
        'data': {'model': 'mti.informe_cp',
                 'output_format': 'xlsx',
                 'options': json.dumps(datas, default=date_utils.json_default),
                 'report_name': 'Excel Report Name',
                 },
    }

def get_informe_cp_report(self):
    datas = self._get_data()
    return self.env.ref('mti_informe_cp.action_report_cp').report_action(self, data=datas)


def _get_data(self):

 result = []
 if self.print_type == 'Sin formato':
    if not self.consignment_note_id == 'Sin formato':
        Sin_formato = self.env['report_sf'].sudo().search([('consignment_note_id', '=', self.consignment_note_id)])
        filtered = self._get_filtered(Sin_formato)

    else:
        Original = self.env['Original'].search([('consignment_note_id', '=', self.consignment_note_id)])
        filtered = self._get_filtered(Original)

 return self.model['mti.carta.porte']
````

pero a la hora de actualizar estos cambios me manda un error en el modelo y la verdad ahorita solo estoy probando ya que debo implementarlo tanto en pdf como en excel igual los reportes ya estan echos y estan incluidos en la carpeta del modulo pero no se si mi estructura este malque podria hacer  o como pdoria corregir esos errore o que me faltaria para que funcione ya estuve probando con otros metodos pero nada funciona

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y ese es el error que manda

````
```Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/opt/odoo14.0/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 639, in 
   _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
    File "/opt/odoo14.0/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 315, in 
  _handle_exception
    raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause
  KeyError: 'mti.carta.porte'```
````

Comment: Por favor pon la traza en texto, no en imagen. Es bastante dificil leerla en imagen.

Comment: cual el error de la termnal?

Comment: Si. Que esperas obtener con esta linea: `return self.model['mti.carta.porte']`?

Comment: pues como ahi estan los campos de la informacion por eso lo puse ya que de ese modelo ligue el campo de carta porte pero no se si esta bien lo que hice porque despues de seleccionar el numero de carta de porte va a elegir cualquiera de las opciones y descargar su formato en pdf o en excel pero eso es lo que esto yhaciendo y si ando bien pedido con eso

Comment: porque incluso los reportes ya los tengo echos solo falta hacer la funcion del filtrado para que busque el documento con el numero que tiene y descargue cualquiera de los formatos del selection ya sea en pdf o en excel

Comment: y toda la informacion que trae el reporte la obtiene de otro modelo @Legna

Comment: Si estas mezclando información de varios modelos y  haciendo un reporte con ello lo mejor es crear un transient model.

Comment: a ok y eso en que parte del codigo va?

Comment: Esa linea debe devolver un registro.

Comment: asi? class Infomecp (models.Tracientmodel):

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140958/discussion-between-carlos-baez-and-legna).

Comment: @Legna ya estuve haciendo modificaciones y nada funciona cuando actualiza el modulo manda error en el key de carta porte pero si genero un reporte manda error en el key del archivo

Comment: Ahora mismo ando corto de tiempo. Pero mira este video para ver si te da algo de guia https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NXTsxtKjllc&themeRefresh=1

Comment: vale gracias lo veo y veo que pùedo hacer

Answer (score 0):

Para generar un reporte lo más recomendable es crear un `model.TransientModel`

```py
class ReporteEspecialCartaPorte(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'reporte_especial_carta_porte'

  # Los campos que necesites.
```

Cuando llames a tu wizard basicamente vas a crear un registro nuevo de este modelo con los datos que necesites. Y de esta estructura vas a generar el reporte en pdf o xml.

## Aclaraciones.

Al parecer, solicitas los datos para el reporte con esta función y lo que estas pasando es un objeto que no existe.

```
def _get_data(self):

 result = []
 if self.print_type == 'Sin formato':
    if not self.consignment_note_id == 'Sin formato':
        Sin_formato = self.env['report_sf'].sudo().search([('consignment_note_id', '=', self.consignment_note_id)])
        filtered = self._get_filtered(Sin_formato)

    else:
        Original = self.env['Original'].search([('consignment_note_id', '=', self.consignment_note_id)])
        filtered = self._get_filtered(Original)
 #-----------------
 #-----------------
 # En esta linea debería retornase un registro, en tu caso el nuevo 
 # transient model (lo creas con miModelo.create(diccionarioDeDatos) )
 #-----------------
 #-----------------
 # REMPLAZAMOS
 #return self.model['mti.carta.porte']
 return miModelo
```

#### A tomar en cuenta

Los transient model son registros temporales en la base de datos. Generalmente se usan para este tipo de acciones donde los datos datos no tienen relevancia más alla del momento actual. Al hacer este cambio tambien tendras que modificar tu template xml para que coincidan los valores con el reporte.

Comment: ok y para que busque o filtre es basica mente igual o iba bien con lo que estaba haciendo con lo de get data?

Comment: Revisa mi edicion

Comment: ok pero bueno eso que puse de sin formato y todo eso son los nombres de los archivos igual los puse como string se podria decir en el slection no se s i por eso este mandando error ya qeu esos de sin formato original y  copia se podria decir que son como la plantilla

Comment: porque solo necesito que busque toda la informacion que vewnga el numero de carta de porte que se valla a ocupar y que haga una descicion con los documentos que estan en el selection si es sin formato que descargue lo que est en el report xml sin formato y lo mismo con original y copia

Comment: por eso es que tengo dudas con la estructur aque estoy ocupando @Legna

Comment: lo puse como lo pusiste en a repuesta  y me manda este error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo14.0/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 639, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/opt/odoo14.0/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 315, in _handle_exception
    raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause
KeyError: 'report_sf

Comment: no se si no lo esta tomando porque es archivo xml o porque?

Comment: hago cambios y cuando actualizo manda el error de carta porte otra vez